# Conditional Formatting, Format if not containing to x or y?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I can use conditioning formatting to highlight the cells not containing X,

Specific text - Not Containing - X

Is there something similar to,

Specific text - Not Containing - X or Y

Comment: Can you share what you used for `Not Containing - X`. Sounds like you just need to amend it with `and` then repeat the equation for other string

Comment: I clicked 'conditional formatting', clicked 'Format only cells that contain', selected 'Specific Text', selected 'Not Containing', and then entered 'X'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a conditional formatting using a formula. If you want to format cell A1 or a range starting at A1 the formula is:

```
=AND(A1<>"X",A1<>"Y")
```